# Fetch records singular and pural wise in varchar and text datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, search, keyword

I've in serious problem that I want solutions.

I want to fetch the records from database.
For example : when I'm searching **Pencils** then I will get 4 records and when I'll searching **Pencil** then I will get 15 records.
But I want 15 records if its searched by Pencils or Pencil.

This is mysql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    gc_products.name,
    gc_products.*,
    LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(saleprice, 0), price),
            price) AS sort_price
FROM
    (`gc_products`)
        JOIN
    `gc_group_product` ON `gc_group_product`.`product_id` = `gc_products`.`id`
        JOIN
    `gc_category_products` ON `gc_category_products`.`product_id` = `gc_products`.`id`
        JOIN
    `gc_categories` ON `gc_categories`.`id` = `gc_category_products`.`category_id`
WHERE
    `gc_products`.`enabled` = 1
        AND `gc_group_product`.`group_id` = 5
        AND (gc_products.name LIKE '%pencils%'
        OR gc_products.description LIKE '%pencils%'
        OR gc_products.excerpt LIKE '%pencils%'
        OR gc_products.sku LIKE '%pencils%')
        OR (gc_categories.name LIKE '%pencils%'
        OR gc_categories.excerpt LIKE '%pencils%');
```

I hope I'll get a reply

Thanks

Comment: You showed us the query for `pencils`, but what about `pencil`?

Comment: You can remove "s" from the keyword which we want to search

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: I'm looking for any text datatype like varchar,text,longtext .Because I have used mix data type in a query

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
gc_products.name,
gc_products.*,
LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(saleprice, 0), price),
        price) AS sort_price
```

FROM
    (`gc_products`)
        JOIN
    `gc_group_product` ON `gc_group_product`.`product_id` = `gc_products`.`id`
        JOIN
    `gc_category_products` ON `gc_category_products`.`product_id` = `gc_products`.`id`
        JOIN
    `gc_categories` ON `gc_categories`.`id` = `gc_category_products`.`category_id`
WHERE
    `gc_products`.`enabled` = 1
        AND `gc_group_product`.`group_id` = 5
        AND (gc_products.name LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(TRAILING BINARY('s') FROM 'pencils'),'%') OR gc_products.description LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(TRAILING BINARY('s') FROM 'pencils'),'%') OR gc_products.excerpt LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(TRAILING BINARY('s') FROM 'pencils'),'%') OR gc_products.sku LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(TRAILING BINARY('s') FROM 'pencils'),'%'))
        OR (gc_categories.name LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(TRAILING BINARY('s') FROM 'pencils'),'%') OR gc_categories.excerpt LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(TRAILING BINARY('s') FROM 'pencils'),'%'));

Comment: Hello 

As per your sql query... 's' will be removed from the pencils but I already used this logic into php. If you have any logic then please give me. Thanks for posting this reply...